# vue-html-to-paper with Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, printing, vuejs3

I'd like to try out vue-html-to-paper and I did the simplest setup according to the documentation. I am using Vue3 though.

```
npm install vue-html-to-paper
```

```
//main.js
[...]
import VueHtmlToPaper from "vue-html-to-paper";

createApp(App)
  .use(VueHtmlToPaper)
  .mount("#app");
```

And my component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="example">
      Hello World
    </div>

    <button @click="print">
      Print
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "my_component",

  methods: {
    print: function() {
      this.$htmlToPaper("example");
    },
  },
</script>
[...]
```

On dev I get an error in console `[...] Cannot set property '$htmlToPaper' of undefined [...]`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, I'd appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It [uses](https://github.com/mycurelabs/vue-html-to-paper/blob/master/src/index.js) `Vue.prototype` so it won't work with Vue 3 unless that's fixed.  You could fork the repo if you wanted to fix it yourself.

To do so, replace this ❌:

```js
install (Vue, options = {}) {
    Vue.prototype.$htmlToPaper = (el, localOptions, cb = () => true) => {
```

with this ✅ which will work for both Vue 2 and Vue 3:

```js
install (Vue, options = {}) {
    let globals = Vue.prototype || Vue.config.globalProperties;
    globals.$htmlToPaper = (el, localOptions, cb = () => true) => {
```

When installing the plugin with Vue 3, follow the [docs](https://randomcodetips.com/vue-html-to-paper/) but replace `Vue.use` with `app.use`.

Comment: Thanks Dan, you are a lifesaver. Found this one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824171/how-to-print-a-specific-element-in-vue-3

Comment: How to fix it for Vue 3 Script setup.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq This is showing how to install it for Vue 3.  It needs no fix for script setup which is also Vue 3.

Comment: @Dan can you confirm how I can access htmlToPaper function in script setup?

Answer (score 3):

I have rewritten the same npm package to be compatible with Vue 3 in typescript.
It's called [paperizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paperizer). You can see full docs [here](https://markhermano.github.io/paperizer/).

The plugin is based from `vue-html-to-paper` and supports both composition API (for those using script setup) and options API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Easy to use composable, worked for me with Vue 3 typescript. Note; while using Vite, I had to exclude 'paperizer' from `optimizeDeps` in vite.config.ts as referred to in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883720/504-outdated-optimize-dep-while-using-react-vite