# 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep) while using react-vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, bigdecimal

I installed a package called *big decimal js* while using React with JavaScript on Vite. On compiling, it showed the following error on the console, and the application did not load:

[image]

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "settleup",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.14",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "firebase": "^9.18.0",
    "js-big-decimal": "^1.4.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.8",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

and Vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 8000,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 61):

Try adding this code to your `vite.config.js` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  ...
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['js-big-decimal']
  }
});
```

then delete your `node_modules` folder and reinstalled all your deps.

There's an ongoing discussion on this issue on github [vite github issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12434).

Comment: yes!! optimizeDeps.exclude was the answer for me!! thank you! for future internet sleuths, I'm using `tesseract-wasm` with vite!

Answer (score 52):

For me it already helped to refresh the browser tab with disabled cache.

In chrome it is `Shift + Ctrl + F5` or `Shift + Cmd + r` on mac.

Comment: Much better than reinstalling vite every time it happens...

Comment: Awesome, saved me a lot of headache!

Answer (score 18):

same like cache problem , have a try

```
"scripts": {
+    "dev": "vite --force",
   "build": "vite build",
   "preview": "vite preview"
 },
```

Comment: sorry, which file in my vite is this?

Comment: @hlin03 this should be in your package.json

Comment: I don't how the issue came from but doing this solved the problem for me. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 16):

Try:

1. Shut down your development server
2. Remove `node_modules/.vite/` directory. If Mac/Linux run `rm -rf node_modules/.vite/`
3. Clear the package manager's cache. If npm run `npm cache clean --force`
4. Reinstall dependencies and start the development server eg. for npm run `npm i && npm run dev`

This should clear the cache and fix it.

Comment: Well done it worked for me.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules/.vite/` is the magic sauce for me - `npm run dev --force` alone was not enough 

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue and I resolved it by stopping application via terminal then rerun it again.

This issue came to me when I had installed bootstrap and react-bootstrap packages, then I uninstalled them and installed mui package instead.

Answer (score 3):

It maybe a cache problem.
check this: https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#browser-cache

Try to clean your cache and restart.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged.  Please include enough of the solution to ensure it will be meaningful if the link becomes invalid.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, I tried stopping and restarting the app using npm run dev.
That worked for me. I had installed sweetalert2 in my react app while running the app opening another terminal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34932049)

Comment: This was actually helpful for me. Stopping and restarting the vite server made the error to go away.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the other answer, if cleaning the vite cache doesn't help try temporarily disabling the cache in the browser. In Chrome press F12, choose network tab and select the Disable cache checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by deleting the vite cache in node_modules (the .vite folder), in a project that I coudlnt do changes, however the top answer seems to be the more longterm solution

Answer (score 1):

Just delete node_modules folder.
then type `npm i` in the terminal again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5310#issuecomment-949349291
This solved the issue for me on arch-based distro:

> On Manjaro Linux (Arch-based), I was able to solve it by adding the following line to both /etc/systemd/system.conf and /etc/systemd/user.conf file:

> DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35761448)

Comment: @RamChander I've literally posted the answer from the link in quotation, what do you even mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with cache. Clean your cache using `yarn cache clean` or `npm cache clean –force` and try running it again. Or else you can simply delete the `node_modules` folder and run it again. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Using below code worked for me. [Reference](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/1632#issuecomment-1208169984)

```
import type { Plugin } from "vite";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";


export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [ reactVirtualized() ], // add
}

const WRONG_CODE = `import { bpfrpt_proptype_WindowScroller } from "../WindowScroller.js";`;
export function reactVirtualized(): Plugin {
    return {
        name: "flat:react-virtualized",
        // Note: we cannot use the `transform` hook here
        //       because libraries are pre-bundled in vite directly,
        //       plugins aren't able to hack that step currently.
        //       so instead we manually edit the file in node_modules.
        //       all we need is to find the timing before pre-bundling.
        configResolved() {
            const file = require
                .resolve("react-virtualized")
                .replace(
                    path.join("dist", "commonjs", "index.js"),
                    path.join("dist", "es", "WindowScroller", "utils", "onScroll.js"),
                );
            const code = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf-8");
            const modified = code.replace(WRONG_CODE, "");
            fs.writeFileSync(file, modified);
        },
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. I won't delve into the solution as it's already been discussed. Instead, I'll address what I believe is the underlying cause.

I faced this while running a web project in Docker, with a volume mounted to the folder containing the source code.

Although most of the internal folders belong to my user account, which is conveniently mapped to the Docker user, an error in my startup script caused the 'node_modules' and 'build' folders to be owned by the root. This led to issues when Vite tried to write assets to these folders during execution.

Ultimately, I didn't delete or recreate the 'node_modules' folder. I simply changed its ownership to my user, and everything started functioning correctly.

Now, to address the root cause, I intend to change the startup script to avoid this situation in the future by running npm commands with my user account instead of root, or, maybe, change ownership after creation.

Answer (score 0):

At Angular 17, I solved that by removing .vite folder inside of .angular folder in the root of the project.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you install a dependency while the **server** was running.
**Restarting** the server solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was ocurring because I was using a different version of node.

- I was in Node v16
- The project was in Node v18

> Note: to not forget about the engines config in `package.json`

```json
{
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This warmup ensures a critical library is pre-loaded to avoid delays when using its hooks on initial page load.

```
server: {
  warmup: {
    clientFiles: [
      "./app/entry.client.tsx",
      "./app/root.tsx",
      "./app/routes/**/*.tsx"
    ],
  },
}
```